# Rounding number: if number is closer to 100, round down to the nearest 250, else round up to the nearest 250

Tags: vb.net, rounding

I'm doing a rounding code for a whole integer. It is already working to round to the nearest `250`.

```
Math.round(FormatNumber(CType(txt_input.Text, Decimal), 0) / 250) * 250
```

However that's not what I need. Instead, I need to round up/down accordingly:
If number is less than `100`, I need to round down to the nearest `250` else round up to the nearest `250`.

Example:

```
17541 = 17500 
2101  = 2250
7499  = 7500
7099  = 7000
```

How should I make the application use `Math.Floor()` or `Math.Ceiling()` accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check whether `N Mod 250` is `< 100`.
If it is, subtract the remainder, otherwise  add `250` minus the remainder:

```
Dim n1 As Integer = 17541
Dim roundToValue As Integer = 250

Dim n1Remainder As Integer = n1 Mod roundToValue
Dim n2 As Integer = If(n1Remainder < 100, n1 - n1Remainder, n1 - n1Remainder + roundToValue)
'Or
'Dim n2 As Integer = (n1 - n1Remainder) + If(n1Remainder < 100, 0, roundToValue)
```

```
2101  -> 2250
7499  -> 7500
17541 -> 17500
```

Comment: Thanks :) this was exactly what i was looking for