# Only certain values are allowed in the text entry box

Tags: vb.net, textbox

do you see a possibility that the user of the program is only allowed to enter certain numbers in a text entry box?
Example:

14785(,00)

14787,50

14790(,00)

So this example is about 2.5 steps. There can also be other steps, for example 1.5 steps. Further requirements are 1) German notation (`,` as decimal separator) and 2) only positive numbers. I already have that.
Because of this grid, I cannot use a `numeric up-down control` and modulo is bad for `double`.

```
Public Class FormMain
    Private Entry As Double = 0R
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Entry)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Entry > 0.0 Then
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Else
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: A Textbox control has a Lines array property, so you could use the OnChanged and/or Leave properties to trigger a check function that examined each item in the Lines array.  If you use On Changed, it's going to trigger with every single character they type, so if the Lines array gets very big it could introduce a noticeable delay.  Just use Regex to validate if each line is in a valid format.

Comment: [Rounding number: if number is closer to 100, round down to the nearest 250, else round up to the nearest 250](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429451/7444103). Of course, use all double values, set `roundToValue = 2.5` and the comparison to `1.0` instead of `100`.

Comment: Hey @technonaut and Jimi Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I multiply the entered Double value by 10.0 and then cast it to `Long`. Then I use `Modulo` to check whether the division by 25L has a remainder of 0L.

```
Public Class FormMain
    Private Entry As Double = 0R
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Entry)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Entry > 0.0 Then
            Dim Eingabe_als_Long As Long = Convert.ToInt64(Entry * 10.0)
            If Eingabe_als_Long Mod 25L = 0L Then
                TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Else
                TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Else
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```